# Does the mobile version of LinkedIn still mess up contacts?

Tags: linkedin, contacts, mobile

When the LinkedIn mobile client was just released I've heard complaints that during/after installation it was combining LinkedIn contacts with the main contact list, creating a mess. So I decided to stick with the desktop version only.

Is it still the case?

Answer (score 1):

Before synchronizing your phone contacts LinkedIn take your permission. It do not do it automatically.

And yes it still do the same with owner permission.

Comment: Just to clarify: I'm OK with LinkedIn importing phone contacts. I do not want it dumping contacts into the phone.

Comment: It dumped contacts into the phone. Android has a setting what contacts you want to see in the contact list. So you can choose accordingly.